# Flutter Web causing state reset when invoking media query

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Take a look...

**file: dashboard.dart**

```
// @dart=2.8
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myApp/Pages/Dashboard/widgets/Episodes/episodes.dart';


class DashboardPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double scrWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width; // if I comment this line, this will work !!!!
    return Container(child: EpisodesWidget());
  }
}
```

**File: episodes.dart**

```
// @dart=2.8
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class EpisodesWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  String nowPlaying = "";
  @override
  _EpisodesWidgetState createState() => _EpisodesWidgetState();
}

class _EpisodesWidgetState extends State<EpisodesWidget> {
  void play(String file) async {
    if (file == widget.nowPlaying) {
      setState(() {
        widget.nowPlaying = "";
      });
    }
    setState(() {
      widget.nowPlaying = file;
    });
    return;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      RowWidget(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          id: '1111',
          currentPlaying: widget.nowPlaying,
          onPlay: (value) => play(value)),
    ]);
  }
}

class RowWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String id;
  final String currentPlaying;
  final ValueChanged onPlay;
  RowWidget({this.id, this.currentPlaying, this.onPlay, Key key})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  _RowWidgetState createState() => _RowWidgetState();
}

class _RowWidgetState extends State<RowWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => widget.onPlay(widget.id + '.mp3'),
      child: MouseRegion(
        cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
        child: Icon(
          widget.currentPlaying == widget.id + '.mp3'
              ? Icons.pause_circle
              : Icons.play_circle,
          color: widget.currentPlaying == widget.id + '.mp3'
              ? Colors.grey
              : Color(0xFFFF8117e),
          size: 25,
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

This example is just a simple example: When you click it, this will toggle between play and pouse icons

this actually works, however if I resize the screen, this go back to the initial state.

So, a test is:

- Execute using Chrome
- Press the play button (this will become a pause button)
- Now resize the screen
- The Pause button was reverted to Play button just because I resized the screen

If I comment the line

```
final double scrWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
```

this will work as expected. The variable `scrWidth` is not being used. So, just a simple assignment to this variable using media query is causing a very weird behavior.

Can someone help me? Is this a Flutter Bug? I am new in Flutter, so maybe it's must me doing things on the wrong way. What is the cause of this? How do I solve it?

Using a suggestion of a colleague that's commented to change everything to stateful, I set the file dashboard.dart to:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:...episodes.dart';

class DashboardPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DashboardPageState createState() => _DashboardPageState();
}

class _DashboardPageState extends State<DashboardPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double scrWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Container(child: EpisodesWidget());
  }
}
```

But I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: MediaQuery doesn't reset anything... resizing the screen calls every build method being used again to get the new screen values. EpisodesWidget() it's being created over and over and over again, making it impossible to hold the state. You need to change your logic or make everything stateful.

Comment: how about using `LayoutBuilder` instead?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, this code is a minimal version of the scenario - Made only to illustrate the issue. There is tons of situations like that all over the project. So I am seeking for the solution or maybe the explanation. But thanks ! I will anyway research about Layour Builder.

Comment: I do understand, no need to he condescending. MediaQuery is being called every time build method is being called, that's how inherited widget works, calling variables inside MediaQuery will request the new windows size information and notifying the render tree. I recommend you to read how Flutter render tree works.

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla Your first comment is incorrect. The issue is they're ignoring analyzer warning and trying to store state within the `StatefulWidget` rather than the `State`. There is no need to change any logic and make any other widgets stateful. Just because `EpisodesWidget` is being created over and over does not mean its state is being destroyed.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore his logic it is incorrect. He's creating an empty string over the stateful part of the widget and, second, he's creating over and over again the UniqueKey() of his widget when that should be created once. He needs to fix nowPlaying where is being created and used.

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla Where is their logic incorrect? Using the UniqueKey is irrelevant here and is not the source of there issue. It's an inefficiency, but not an issue. Your first comment makes the claim that they need to make ***everything*** stateful, which is unfounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug with Flutter. This is an issue with your code. Your `nowPlaying` `String` is not actually a part of your widget's state. Move it into the state:

```dart
class EpisodesWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  //Widget state should not be stored here!

  @override
  _EpisodesWidgetState createState() => _EpisodesWidgetState();
}

class _EpisodesWidgetState extends State<EpisodesWidget> {
  String nowPlaying = "";//Store it here!

  void play(String file) async {
    if (file == widget.nowPlaying) {
      setState(() {
        widget.nowPlaying = "";
      });
    }
    setState(() {
      widget.nowPlaying = file;
    });
    return;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      RowWidget(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          id: '1111',
          currentPlaying: widget.nowPlaying,
          onPlay: (value) => play(value)),
    ]);
  }
}
```

---

Please do not ignore analyzer warnings in the future. You should have been getting a warning about widget classes being immutable, caused by trying to store state within the widget itself.

---

When you do `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;` you're listening for changes in the screen width of your application. Each time the widget changes, your `DashboardPage` widget with call `build` again. This then *recreates* `EpisodesWidget` and the `nowPlaying` variable you previously stored there.

Moving `nowPlaying` to the state removes this issue as the state exists separately from the widget itself. The state will persist as long as the widget persists in the widget tree.

Comment: Thanks ! and Yes, you are right. As I mentioned I am new in Flutter. SO it could be something that I was doing wrong, some conceptual thing. Thank you !

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla There's no need to be toxic. We may have a different definition of what "logic" is. The *only* "issue" is that they declared a variable in the wrong scope, which I personally consider far from logic. I also took issue with your declaration that the issue lay somewhere with `UniqueKey` and also your implication in your first comment that a widget being created over and over again is somehow a problem in Flutter and was destroying state, which is definitely is not. I would recommend reading about the widget and element trees and how they interact.